# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443 when calling a POST request inside a GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-post

I'm not sure whether what I did is the right way to implement or not.

Here is what I have tried, I'm making a GET request to fetch data from Google and then I need to send data to my Server via POST request.

When I'm making the post request I'm getting the below error:

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
```

Code in NodeJS

```
  request({
  url: 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?requestMask.includeField=person.photos,person.emailAddresses,person.names',
  auth: {
          'bearer': access_token
        }

  }, function(err, response) {

   if(err)
   {
       res.status(500).send({ error: " Info error", data: null, message: "Error" });
       res.end();
   }
   else
   {
       var res_data  = JSON.parse(response.body);
       var username  = res_data.names[0].displayName;
       var userid    = res_data.names[0].metadata.source.id;
       var data = {name: username,id:userid};

        postToApp(data, (postResponse) => {

          //respond back with the result/error to your API
          console.log(postResponse);
        });
    }
    });
```

postToApp Function

```
 function postToApp(data, callback) {

 var options = {
url : 'https://localhost/:3333/saveInfo',
method : 'POST',
body : data,
json : true
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
console.log(error + response + body);
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  console.log(body);
  callback(body) // call the function back with the data you want to process;
} else {
  console.log('Error from server is' + error);
  callback(error) // call the function back with error to process;
}

  });
}
```

Comment: Typo in `https://localhost/:3333/saveInfo`. Remove the slash (/) before the colon: `https://localhost:3333/saveInfo`. The way you have it `3333` is not interpreted as port number but as part of the URI path and the request is sent to standard HTTPS port (443).

Comment: @marekful damn! thanks a lot for pointing it out.